# How to make Gmail's "reply to all" default?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I don't want to constantly remember to press **reply to all**, how to make that the default action even if I press "reply" instead. We're using G Suite Gmail at the company.

Comment: If you use keyboard shortcuts, A = reply all, and R = reply

Comment: @ElliottB Wow! this is the answer I want, enable shortcuts and then press A. Your answer is the best.

Comment: glad I could help. I made it an answer just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First enable keyboard shortcuts under Gmail settings. Then press A for reply all, or R for reply. From any page, you can press ? To get a list of available shortcuts.

Answer (score 4):

- enter Gmail **Settings**
- under **General** selection you will find **Default reply behaviour**:

  [image]

Comment: I just found out that this doesn't do what I want, it still the same, just the order of the button has changed, I can still reply. I want that even if I press reply, it replies to all.

Comment: this is all you can get. it's not possible to rewire the button so both of them would act as you wish. however, it would be possible to remove the button with AdblockPlus so you will be left only with the one button you need